# how to use mysql procedure in mybatis(select statement)?

Tags: mysql, spring, mybatis, procedure

I have created a procedure that calls the table again with the results dynamically obtained from the query.

I called the procedure in MYBATIS using the SELECT statement, but an error occurs.

```
TABLE : TEMP
| tableinfo | columninfo |
| -------- | -------- |
| table1   | column1   |
| table1   | column2   |
| table2   | column3   |
| table2   | column4   |


TABLE : table1
| column1 | Column2 |
| -------- | -------- |
| tom   | white   |
| jack   | red   |

TABLE : table2
| column3 | Column4 |
| -------- | -------- |
| 2021   | 10.2   |
| 2022   | 9.9   |
```

i made procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `INSERT_DATA`(columnName varchar(40), tableName varchar(40))
BEGIN

  set @s := concat("insert into DATA_DB select ", columninfo , " from ", tableinfo ");
   prepare stmt from @s;
   execute stmt;
   deallocate prepare stmt;
   
END
```

and i use mybatis and made some select xml

```
    <select id="callProc" statementTyle="CALLABLE">
        SELECT
            {CALL INSERT_DATA(T.tableinfo, T.columninfo)}
        FROM 
            TEMP T
    </select>
```

BUT that is SQLSyntaxErrorException.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot CALL a stored procedure from a SELECT. See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) for procedure usage.